# Does any change in an array gets to change the entire array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I got into that question by thinking about sorting algorithms.

Does changing an element position inside an array would be the same, at the interpretation, compilation or run-time phases, to recreate the entire array with new elements? 
Does it change radically from one language to another? 
**How does it work?**

Imagining a specific case in JavaScript, for example:

```js
let animals = ["monkey","zebra","banana","capybara"];

animals.splice(2,1); // returns ["banana"]
```

Would it be correct to state that the entire `animals` array was rewritten? Or is there another type of change type? How would that one and only change work, computation-wise?

<del>It's stated in Javascript documentation that the `.splice()` method "takes" an array object, creates a new array without it and returns another one with it as an output, but **how does it work?**</del>

I'm a begginner, so please have patience, and would like a good reading recommendation if possible to learn more about it. Sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: "t's stated in Javascript documentation..." - what documentation are you referring to? Please provide a link.

Comment: https://itnext.io/v8-deep-dives-understanding-array-internals-5b17d7a28ecc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does changing an element position inside an array would be the same, at the interpretation, compilation or run-time phases, to recreate the entire array with new elements?

I think you're asking this:

> Does changing an element position inside an array recreate the entire array with new elements?

- If you use the array indexer `[]`, then **no**: the array is not recreated, it's *mutated* in-place.
- If you use `Array.prototype.splice`, then **no**: the array is not recreated, it's *mutated* in-place.

  - <sub>But `splice` *does* return a new array containing the removed elements.</sub>
- If you use `Array.prototype.filter` and/or `Array.prototype.map`, then **yes**: a new array containing only the filtered elements is returned (and the original input array is unmodified at all: i.e. *nothing is mutated*).
- If you use `Array.prototype.forEach` to assign elements back to itself (*which you shouldn't be doing anyway*), then **no**: the array is mutated in-place.

---

> Imagining a specific case in JavaScript, for example:
>
> ```js
> let animals = ["monkey","zebra","banana","capybara"];  
> animals.splice(2,1); // returns ["banana"]
> ```
>
> Would it be correct to state that the entire `animals` array was rewritten?

No. That would be incorrect.

The correct thing to say is that "the `animals` array was mutated".

> It's stated in Javascript documentation that the `.splice()` method "takes" an array object, creates a new array without it and returns another one with it as an output, but how does it work?

I don't know what "JavaScript documentation" you're referring to, but that is incorrect.

The only authoritative sources for JavaScript documentation are either [the official ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) or documentation provided by JavaScript engine vendors (such as Mozilla's Spidermonkey) documented on MDN.

Sources such as W3Schools are not authoritative.

...and MDN says this about `splice` (emphasis mine):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
>
> The `splice()` method **changes the contents of an array** by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements **in place**.

---

> how does it work?

The inner-workings of the `splice` function [are defined in the ECMAScript specification (section 23.1.3.29)](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.splice).

...which can be summarized as:

1. Given a `splice` invocation with arguments `( this: Array, start: int, deleteCount: int );`...
2. Create a new array to hold `deleteCount` items: `deletedItems`.
3. Copy elements in `this` from index `start` to `start + deleteCount` into `deletedItems`.
4. Copy elements in `this` from `start + deleteCount` to `this.length` *upwards* to fill the gap of removed items.
5. Shrink the `length` to `this.length - deleteCount`.

In TypeScript, *something like this* (ignoring handling of negative arguments):

```js
function splice<T>( this: T[], start: int, deleteCount: int ): T[] {
    
    const removedItems: T[] = [];
    const tailIdx = start + deleteCount;

    for( let i = start; i < tailIdx; i++ ) {
        removedItems.push( this[i] );
    }

    for( let i = tailIdx, f = start; i < this.length; i++, f++ ) {
        this[i] = this[f];
    }

    this.length = this.length - deleteCount;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! 
Because of my inexperience, I couldn't  build my question in a better way, but that's right, that was what I was asking. 
Thanks for correcting me and for explaining!